# Magento2 Hide Custom Tab based on Condition

Tags: magento2, xml, product-view

I have created custom tab in Magento2 in my Custom module. The code used to make tab was using xml like -

```
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Vendor\Faq\Block\Product\View\Details\Faqtab" name="vendorFaqtab" template="Vendor_Faq::product/view/details/faqtab.phtml" group="detailed_info"/>                     
        </referenceBlock>
```

I want to be able to show hide the tab based on a check in admin. Like show in frontend yes/no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *ifconfig* in your xml to implement this.

example

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Vendor\Faq\Block\Product\View\Details\Faqtab" name="vendorFaqtab" ifconfig='mymodule/Myblockclass/enable' template="Vendor_Faq::product/view/details/faqtab.phtml" group="detailed_info"/>                     
        </referenceBlock>
```

And you need to create a class file in you Block

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;
class Myblockclass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link {

    public function toHtml() {return !mycondition() ? parent::toHtml() : '';}
}
```

Note : Read the admin configuration in mycondition fucntion

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple; just go to Stores → Configuration → Core Configuration → Product Details → Tabs, and select Custom Tab No from the drop down.

See the screenshot:

[image]