# Hide tab on product page on certain condition in magento 2.3.3

Tags: ifconfig

I am trying to use ifconfig to hide a tab but it is not working properly below is my code please check

```
<?php
namespace Afg\Hidetab\Block;
class hidetab extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link {
    /**
     * @override
     * @see \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link::toHtml()
     * @return string
     */
    public function toHtml() {return true ? parent::toHtml() : '';}
}
```

=========

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="hidetab" ifconfig='Afg_Hidetab/hidetab/enable' template="Afg_Hidetab::hidetab.phtml"  group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Lava Calculator</argument>
            </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: attach system.xml file

Comment: there is no system.xml file in my module

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/121

Comment: i am trying to follow the above link

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238893/magento2-hide-custom-tab-based-on-condition

Comment: ifconfig='Afg_Hidetab/hidetab/enable' means ????

Comment: this means ifconfig='SectionId/GroupId/Field'

Comment: can u more elaborate it

Comment: hide tab based on which condition ???

Comment: base on product category

Comment: basically it is calculator and i have to show different calculator for different category